# Expired Israeli student visa - returning to Israel on this?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, israel, study

I am a U.S  citizen and have an expired Israeli student visa which I used to study in Israel for two years. I now plan to go back for another year of study. Will I be able to enter the country on my expired student visa?

Answer (score 4):

No.  The visa is valid for a fixed period of time, which I'm sure you realise as you use the  term 'expired'.

It usually has a date on the visa, and if that date is in the past, you can not use it in the present or future.

You'll need to get a new student visa, or you will be turned away when you try to board your flight.

Comment: More likely, he'll be allowed on the flight, as Israel doesn't require advance tourist visas from Western or most other developed countries. But a tourist visa is what he will get on arrival. It is (or at least used to be) *possible* to get a student visa once inside Israel but it is much easier to get it before leaving. Going to school on the tourist visa, even if the school doesn't check, will be a problem because the visa will run out.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus fair point.  I guess what I'm saying is - the student visa itself is invalid, but there are other ways in (like tourist on arrival visa)